# Resizing UIImageView according to UIImage Ratio is not working

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, sdwebimage

I have an UIImageView Container, the setup is here:

```
    let moviePosterContainer = UIImageView()
    customView.addSubview(moviePosterContainer)
    moviePosterContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    moviePosterContainer.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    moviePosterContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    moviePosterContainer.clipsToBounds = true
    
    moviePosterContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    moviePosterContainer.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

How I add an UImage:

```
    moviePosterContainer.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: moviePosterPath),
                   placeholderImage: UIImage(),
                   options: [],
                   completed: { (image, error,cacheType, url) in
            // here image is the UIImage

                        print("image size height width")
                        
                        print(image.size.height)
                        print(image.size.width)
                        
                    print("image sizes")
                    
                    //let ratio = (image?.size.width)! / (image?.size.height)!
                    
                    if let image = image {
                        let ratio = image.size.width / image.size.height
                        print("image ratio w")
                        print(ratio)
                        
                        print("image ratio h")
                        print(image.size.height / image.size.width)

                        if customView.frame.width > customView.frame.height {
                            print("is first")
                            let newHeight = customView.frame.width / ratio
                            print("new height")
                            print(newHeight)
                            moviePosterContainer.frame.size = CGSize(width: customView.frame.width, height: newHeight)
                            print("container frame size first")
                            print(moviePosterContainer.frame.size)
                            
                            print("container ratio")
                            print(newHeight / customView.frame.height)
                        }
                        else{
                            print("is second")
                            let newWidth = customView.frame.height * ratio
                            print("new width")
                            print(newWidth)
                            moviePosterContainer.frame.size = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: self.kolodaView1.frame.height)
                            print("container frame size second")
                            print(moviePosterContainer.frame.size)
                            
                            print("container ratio w")
                            print(newWidth / customView.frame.height)
                            
                            print("container ratio h")
                            print(customView.frame.height / newWidth)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    moviePosterContainer.image = image
                    moviePosterContainer.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    })
```

Console Output:

```
image size height width
750.0
500.0
image ratio w
0.6666666666666666
image ratio h
1.5
is second
new width
288.0
container frame size second
(288.0, 440.0)
container ratio w
0.6666666666666666
container ratio h
1.5
```

You can see, my UImageView has the same Ratio as the UImage.

But my UIImage in the UImageView is still not correctly displayed. It looks like the UImage is still bigger than my container. ScaleToFit has no effect.

Why is the UIImage not displayed correctly? Is it because the original image size?

Comment: Don't manually set the frame of views that are managed by autolayout. Just set the appropriate `contentMode` and either a ratio constraint or a constraint for one of the dimensions (where the other one would be automatically resized). Even in the case that you need to calculate the ratio yourself, don't do it manually, [there is a function for this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/1390116-avmakerect).

Comment: Could you ellaborate your answer a little bit? This is very new to me. I got it work by resizing the UImage Frame. But now I think this is not correct after reading your answer.

Comment: The idea of autolayout is that you don't have to manually set frames anymore. They (frames) are calculated by satisfying all the constraints you have put (right now you only center the imageview to its parent). So for example a contentmode of `scaleAspectFit` with a width constraint of `320` would fit your image into a `320 x <height_maintaining_original_ratio>`. I hope that this makes sense...